# Missing -connection parameter in Connect-PnPOnline

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online, pnp.powershell

The current Connect-PnPOnline documentation lists a -Connection parameter:
https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Connect-PnPOnline.html#-connection

but in PnP.PowerShell v1.12.0 I can't see that parameter. It looks like this is something that is due to be added as mentioned on this link:

https://github.com/pnp/powershell/pull/2821

Is the absence a -Connection parameter a case of the documentation having been updated before the command is fully available or am I missing something.

[You can see the parameters currently available in the attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n43ne.png)

Thanks in advance for the clarification!

...

Comment: Does `(Get-Command Connect-PnPOnline).Parameters['Connection']` output anything?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, the documentation (and module) was updated two weeks ago to include that parameter:

https://github.com/pnp/powershell/commit/38a30051798f5d1452c479a630c146c148b64375

`PnP.PowerShell` v1.12.0 is 4 months old:

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PnP.PowerShell/

Try installing one of the nightly builds, or wait for a stable release